# ASP.NET: cannot find [name].designer.aspx.cs in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, code-behind

maybe it's a dumb question,

how can i see the designer generated codebehind files (named .designer.aspx.cs) in VS2010?

i need it to wireup form events when i disable autowireup option at @form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a website. Websites don't have designer files. If you create a web application,

File - New Project - Web - ASP.NET Web Application

you will see the designer files.

Comment: Can also right click on the project an select "convert to web applicaton"

Answer (score 0):

Next to the file, there is an arrow which you can expand to see the code-behind and designer files.

See here:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/62bba0f898.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/62bba0f898.png)

Comment: i can't see the second file there 

what option can i change?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i can't see the second file like in the previous answer - only the regular .cs file.

see the screenshot

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/74de60f240.png

i can't post images inline till i get 10 points - sorry for link.

Comment: That looks bizarre. Even the icon for the web site looks different....

How did you create that project/solution? File -> New Project -> Then what?